# Stepping through ASP.NET MVC 2 source

Tags: asp.net-mvc, debugging, asp.net-mvc-2

I've been trying to set up the [ASP.NET MVC 2 RTM Source](http://aspnet.codeplex.com/releases/view/41742) for use with my app, so I can step through things like model binding when debugging.  However, I haven't been able to get it to work - **I'm getting errors like:**

```
The type 'System.Web.Mvc.Controller' is defined in an assembly that is not referenced. 
You must add a reference to assembly 'System.Web.Mvc, Version=2.0.0.0, Culture=neutral,
PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35'.

The type 'System.Web.Mvc.Async.AsyncControllerActionInvoker' is defined in an assembly that is not referenced. 
You must add a reference to assembly 'System.Web.Mvc, Version=2.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, 
PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35'.
```

Etc...

I followed the steps in [Steve Sanderson's howto](http://blog.stevensanderson.com/2009/02/03/using-the-aspnet-mvc-source-code-to-debug-your-app/) (for MVC1), but perhaps there are different steps to get it to work in MVC2?

**Steps I have taken so far:**

- Removed references to GAC based `System.Web.Mvc dll` from all of my projects.
- Added the MVC source as a project in the solution.
- Added references to the System.Web.Mvc project in each of my projects.
- Commented out the `<add assembly="System.Web.Mvc...` item in the `<compilation><assemblies>` section of the root `web.config`
- Commented out the `<add assembly="System.Web.Mvc...` item in the  section of the `web.config` in the `Views` folder (and the `Views` folders of each of the areas)
- Find/replaced any of the references to `System.Web.Mvc, Version=2.0.0.0` and replaced their `PublicKeyToken` value with `null` (was 31bf3856ad364e35)

**So, questions:**

- has anyone else got this working? (presumably yes!)
- Where are the `PublicKeyToken` numbers coming from in the errors?
- There are some other references to this same `PublicKeyToken` (31bf3856ad364e35) for other dlls in the `web.config` (e.g. `System.Web.Extensions`) is this relevant?
- Any idea what I'm doing wrong?!  Steps I've missed?

Thank you!

**UPDATE:**
In response to Syd's questions, here's some extra info:

1) Current assemblies node from web.config:

```
<compilation debug="true">
    <assemblies>
        <add assembly="System.Core, Version=3.5.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=B77A5C561934E089"/>
        <add assembly="System.Web.Extensions, Version=3.5.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31BF3856AD364E35"/>
        <add assembly="System.Web.Abstractions, Version=3.5.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31BF3856AD364E35"/>
        <add assembly="System.Web.Routing, Version=3.5.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31BF3856AD364E35"/>
        <add assembly="System.Web.Mvc, Version=2.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=null"/>
        <add assembly="System.Data.DataSetExtensions, Version=3.5.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=B77A5C561934E089"/>
        <add assembly="System.Xml.Linq, Version=3.5.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=B77A5C561934E089"/>
        <add assembly="System.Data.Linq, Version=3.5.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=B77A5C561934E089"/>
    </assemblies>
</compilation>
```

2) Yes, I am using MVC Futures, but have that project built in my solution too, and have referenced it to use the System.Web.Mvc in the solution.

3) I am using a few non-standard references. Rather that a screenshot I'll list them here:

```
Autofac
Autofac.Integration.Web
Autofac.Integration.Web.Mvc
Elmah
FluentValidation
FluentValidation.Mvc
log4net
MvcContrib
MySql.Data
NHibernate
MvcFutures
```

Answer (score 3):

You don't need to download the source code or remove references from the GAC. Just follow the steps described in [this blog post](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/archive/blogs/sburke/configuring-visual-studio-to-debug-net-framework-source-code).

- Uncheck: Enable Just My Code (Managed only)
- Check: Enable source server support
- Add symbols server: In VS2010 you only need to check the `Microsoft Symbols Servers`, no need to enter url, in VS2008 you need to enter the url

Create a new ASP.NET MVC application, put a breakpoint in your controller action and when the breakpoint gets hit, load the symbols for the `System.Web.Mvc` assembly from the call stack and once the symbols are loaded you will be able to step through the source code (after accepting the terms and conditions).

Comment: Yeah, I would have preferred doing it that way, but my current draconian network setup means eternal source servers are not an option.  This might be the way I have to go eventually though if I can't get the source working.

Comment: Meant 'external', not 'eternal' in that previous comment of course ;)

Answer (score 1):

Instead of commenting out the `<assemblies><add assembly>` lines, you should set the PublicKeyToken=null instead.

Comment: Ok, just tried this and still get the same errors I'm afraid.

Comment: More questions. 1) Can you list your modified lines in the "assemblies" node? 2) Can you do a screen capture of the References in your project? 3) Also are you using the MVC futures?

Comment: Thanks, I've updated the question with the info you requested :)

Comment: Your other DLLs (e.g. Autofac and FluentValidation) may be dependent on the released version of Mvc. Please try bindingRedirect - See http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/eftw1fys.aspx